# Spring boot not compiling

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to compile the project `https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws` but the parent project has references to `flatten-maven-plugin` thus i am getting the error.

If this plugin is public i am not sure why i am getting the error as below. I am not able to get rid of this plugin. I opened a ticket on the git project but as it may not gather any answer.

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:flatten-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\ranajit.jana\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository pom.xml /spring-cloud-aws-**** line 1 Maven pom Loading Problem
```

I am compiling this code as i want to make some changes.

Anyone has idea what can be done ?

=============================

This is resolved now.

This is was repo issue the plugin repo was pointing to repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 which could not resolve this plugin.

I had to add the following to resolve this issue..
This is added as one additional plugin repo

```
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>maven-plugin-repo-mvn</id>
                <name>Maven plugin repo maven</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the .m2/repository and proceed to the path **org/codehaus/mojo/flatten-maven-plugin/.** There delete the subdirectory version number. and all contained files. Maven will automatically download them the next time they are required.